# html “lang” attribute changed font settings

Tags: html, css, fonts, bootstrap-4

Html lang attribute changes some div fonts and colors to bootstrap default ones. I have added  `<html lang="en">` and am using Bliss2 Regular font. Here is the defualt font style which is taken.

```
.cc-revoke, .cc-window {
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box;
**font-family: Helvetica,Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;**
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5em;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

Here is my code:

```
.cc-window {
**font-family: "Bliss Regular";**
font-size: 16px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Why this is happening? How can i fix this. This is happening only in some parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `!important` at the end of the styles you wish to override:

```
font-size : 16px !important ;
```

Comment: I would like to know the reason for this?. Why it happens when enabling the lang attribute

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but from your description of the problem, I believe the issue is coming from specificity level. When you change the lang attribute, it is possible that the styling for those html objects linked to that attribute change becomes more specific than it used to be, therefore overriding the styling you had intially coded for it. You can read more about that here:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/css-specificity-and-inheritance/